# Neuroevolution is not converging (Genetic Algorithm + Neural Network)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, neural-network, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to make my first neuroevolution example and even though I believe the logic is okay, for some reason it is not working.

I've set a population of 20 creatures with a random generated brain and random genes. A brain is a neural network with 3 layers:

1. The first one has only 1 neuron and receives the n-step (step 1,
   step 2 and so on) applying a linear function to it (y=x)
2. The 2nd layer has 23 neurons which represents the 23 steps needed to
   reach the exit also applying a linear function,
3. The final layer has 1 neuron that outputs where to move applying
       this function `Math.floor(Math.abs(3.9 * Math.sin(x)))`
       so i get values between [0, 3] which i use to determine where to
       move (0=north, 1=east, 2=south, 3=west).

The genes represents weights and bias for each neuron which are randomly generated as previously stated.

Every creature makes 23 steps, every square adds 100 points to the fitness if it's part of the path_to_exit otherwise it won't add nothing. Once you've stepped onto a square that's part of the path_to_exit it will add no points the next time you step on it, so you don't get extra points by stepping more than once the same square.

After all creatures have been evaluated, I select the one with the best fitness score and the ones with 70% or more of that score. For example: if our fitness results for 3 creatures were 1000, 800, 600 we'll choose the one with 1000 and the one with 800 because 800 is higher than 1000*70%. We will **always** select at least 2 of them, even though the 2nd one doesn't meet the 70% restriction, in that case it will be the one with the 2nd best score. All the others are deleted.

Next we'll proceed to crossover by selecting 2 random creatures (obviously different from each other). For crossover i use single crossover, selecting a random number N between 1 and 23 and copying the 1~N genes of the A father and N~23 genes of the B father. Then it has 5% of mutating each gene of each cromosome. We repeat this process until we've generated 20 new creatures.

The problem is that I'm not getting any enhancement at all. All creatures are getting around 100-500 fitness every generation, sometimes 1 or 2 reach 1000 even 1500 but they won't keep that score for next generation. I've run it for 10k generations and am still getting 100-500 fitness score.

What am I doing wrong? Is my logic okay?

Here's a link where you can test it: http://salazarseijas.com/geneticgame/

I've some logs there which can help you check something you guys might need. On the right side of the website you'll see C1=, C2=, etc, those are the fitness score for each creature.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: I've implemented a multiplier when adding square points. It multiplies the square fitness by how good the creature has been doing so far. Here's the multiplier:

```
var multiplier = ((this.total_good_sqm == 0 ? 1 : this.total_good_sqm) / (this.total_bad_sqm == 0 ? 1 : this.total_bad_sqm));
```

Also changed 70% threshold to 50%

EDIT 2: Raised population size from 20 to 500 as JanŽegklitz suggested. Also, now 10% best creatures from generation N are copied exactly to generation N+1.

EDIT 3: I'm switching to C# because i realize something's wrong with Javascript. Look at the console and pause when a generation ends, you'll see a text `WE PUSH THE FIRST ONE #: array` where # means the "best_ones" length, which should be 1 since we're pushing the 1st one to it, but surprise, click on the array and you'll see it has the entire population. I don't get what's going on here. If you wanna check by yourself it's in the file genetic_algorithm_class.js

```
var best_ones = [];

var best_fitness = this.population[0].fitness;

for (var i = 0; i < this.population.length; i++)
{
    var c = this.population[i];
    console.log(c)

    if (i == 0) 
    {
        best_ones.push(c);
        console.log("WE PUSH THE FIRST ONE " + best_ones.length + ": ", best_ones)
        continue;
    }

    if (this.population[i].fitness >= best_fitness * BEST_ONE_THRESHOLD /*&& best_ones.length > parseInt(this.population.length * MAX_ELITISM)*/)
    {
        console.log("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Pushing ");
        best_ones.push(c);
    }
}
```

Previously i had it like `var best_ones = [this.population[0]];` but after trying different ways it always shows the entire `this.population` when printing `best_ones` with 1 element inside it.

Comment: Interesting question. Can you make it a more specific question though?

Comment: Why it's not converging? Why am i getting same fitness results after 10k generations ?

Comment: It seems to me that you are deleting everything except the top 30% of fitnesses. Am I right? If I am, then it is very likely to get stuck in some local optimum. Try to use more conventional genetic optimisation strategy - have a population, select individuals based on some reasonable strategy (I recommend tournament selection), based on some probability crossover the selected pairs, based on some probability mutate the selected and/or crossovered solutions and then put them back into the main population (either in generational fashion or steady-state fashion).

Comment: I know i can get stuck in some local optimum, that's where mutation comes in (right?). I don't think implementing tournament selection will help here because i'm trying at least to preserve the genes of the best one in a specific generation which i believe will make creatures to keep the score over time. For example if 3 creatures reached 1000 pts in N generation i'm expecting them to keep at least 800-1000+ over the N+1 generations, but they all keep getting low scores at 1k+ generations. I've seen better scores on the 1st generation than 1k+ generation. @JanŽegklitz

Comment: I'll implement a pts multiplier for each consecutive optimum step. I'll update my question when done.

Comment: Not losing the best solution is usually done through elitism - the top individuals (how many is your choice) are copied straight to the next generation. The rest of the population is filled by those selected, crossed over and mutated. You are doing basically only the elitism. Mutation is supposed to get out of the local optima but a mutation done on a good individual will probably make it worse which you will probably throw away in your setting. Also try to increase the population size. 20 sounds to me like s terribly small one to evolve such a complex thing like neural network parameters.

Comment: Okay, i will try and post back results. Thank you

Comment: Maybe check out [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic), it has built-in neuro-evolution :)